# Qt centralwidget toolbar splitter

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qsplitter, qtoolbar

I am working on a Qt project based on QMainwindow having left and right toolbars. What is the better way to add splitter between QMainwindow and toolbars. As in Qt creator we have splitters between code editor and other panels.

Central widget, right and left toolbars with splitters in a Horizontal layout will work but... looking for a better solution.

Comment: If you want to place widget around your central widdget, [QDockWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#details) may be enough for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QToolBar`s have fixed height (or width if they are vertical) by design. You really should use `QDockWidget` instead. It acts like `QToolBar` in many aspects, but allows to place arbitrary content in it. Just insert `QToolButton`s in it to make it an analog of normal toolbar.